# How to specify region for functions using Angular Fire Module?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2

I'm using `@angular/fire"` AKA `AngularFireModule` `v6.1.5` and want to know how to actually pass region information so that I could use functions on other regions.

This didn't work:

```
import { REGION } from '@angular/fire/functions';


export class Region {
  public static get getRegion() {
    const storageService = new StorageService();
    const runtimeConfig = storageService.secureStorage.getItem("runtimeConfig");
    console.log(runtimeConfig); // { "functionsRegion": "us-east4" }
    const value = runtimeConfig?.["functionsRegion"] ?? "us-central1"; // "us-east4"
    console.log("getRegion: ", value) // us-east4
    return value;
  }
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: REGION, useValue: Region.getRegion }
  ]
})
```

I'm receiving and storing Runtime Config correctly, but functions calls are still using `us-central1`.

Works now after these changes:

1- Forgot to add `AngularFireFunctionsModule` to imports.

2- Function calls were done using the `firebase` library instead of Angular Fire:

This didn't work:

```
import firebase from "firebase";

firebase.functions().httpsCallable("helloWorld")(); // us-central1
```

This however worked:

```
// constructor
private fns: AngularFireFunctions


//function 
const callable = this.fns.httpsCallable('helloWorld'); // us-east1

//call 
callable(null).subscribe(res => console.log({ res }));
```

Comment: Did you see https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/functions/functions.md#functions-region and for example https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2909. If thst doesn't work for you, please edit your question to [show what you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No, I couldn't reach the first link with my search, but did come across the second link but wasn't related to my question since it was about a later version of the library. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction though.

Comment: I updated the question, since the suggestion is not working.

Comment: Works now, updated as well. Though I think it became different than the other answer, so re-opening and accepting an answer would help other people.