# How to make the functions region switch to another when it becomes down using Angular Fire Module?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2

When calling Firebase Functions from Angular using Angular Fire, default region is set to `us-central1`. A couple of months ago the whole region was down, and as a result all functions were inaccessible.

What I'm trying to do now is figure out a way to dynamically change the functions location to another at the time of calling.

The functions will be deployed to multiple regions obviously.

But how to handle that on the client side?

Is there a documented way to implement this using Firebase/Google Cloud?

Here's the code I currently have to switch functions region manually(which requires a new build and deployment):

```
import { REGION } from '@angular/fire/functions';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: REGION, useValue: 'asia-northeast1' }
  ]
})
```

Comment: What sort of functions are you invoking (callable or normal http functions)?  Could you share the code you have now so we can see what you're doing?

Comment: Most are callable functions(a few normal ones). I'll update the question.

Comment: The general documentation shows how to do this. Maybe there is something similar for angular, which is built on top of the web sdk. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#client-side_location_selection_for_callable_functions

Comment: The code snippet I have already does that. My problem is how to make the process work on it's own? For example: When `us-central1` is down, change region to another region that is not down.

Comment: You would have to implement that manually.  There is no automatic failover.  You will need to know that a region is down in order to avoid using it in your code.

Comment: Do you happen to know where to start? Like is this something a load balancer can do? 
And if so, how would Angular Fire use the URL?

Comment: I managed to implement something using runtime config, but Angular Fire doesn't appear to be using the region value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75056824/how-to-specify-region-for-functions-using-angular-fire-module